# Which code runs faster?

Tags: java, performance

I have two piece of code, and I want to know which is faster when they run and why it's faster. I learn less about JVM and CPU, but I'm hard working on them. Every tip will help.

```
int[] a=new int[1000];
int[] b=new int[10000000];
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//method 1
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<10000000;j++){
        a[i]++;
    }
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end-start);

start=System.currentTimeMillis();
//method 2
for(int i=0 ;i<10000000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<1000;j++){
        b[i]++;
    }
}
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end-start);
```

Comment: And when you run this what do you get?

Comment: What prevents you from measuring?

Comment: What does your benchmark say?

Comment: both will be take same time `(10000000*1000)`

Comment: 21396 and 20400 respectively

Comment: My eclipse show that method 1 is faster,but i don't know why and i just want to know why it's faster

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Not necessarily. It might be negligible, but I'd suspect the larger `b`, non-contiguous memory, blah blah blah might have an effect.

Comment: @WilliamGaul too much minute calculation, lets run the code :)

Comment: I think 10000000 * 1000 = 1000 * 10000000...:)

Answer (score 5):

**Complexity**

In terms of asymptotic complexity (e.g. big-O notation), they have the same running time.

**Data localization**

Ignoring any optimization for the moment...

`b` is larger and is thus more likely to be split across multiple (or more) [pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29). Because of this, the first is likely faster.

The difference here is likely to be rather small, unless not all of these pages fit into RAM and need to be written to disk (which is unlikely here since `b` is only 10000000*4 = 40000000 bytes = 38 MB).

**Optimization**

The first method involves "execute `a[i]++` 10000000 times" (for a fixed `i`), which can theoretically rather easily be converted to `a[i] += 10000000` by the optimizer.

A similar optimization can occur for `b`, but only to `b[i] += 1000`, which still has to run 10000000 times.

The optimizer is free to do this or not do this. As far as I know, the Java language specification doesn't say much about what should and shouldn't be optimized, as long as it doesn't change the end result.

As an extreme result, the optimizer could, in theory, see that you're not doing anything with `a` or `b` after the loops and thus get rid of both loops.

Comment: you can comment a[i]++ and b[i]++ and will see that mothing change. First will fuster. :)

Answer (score 5):

I'll throw my answer in there, in theory they will be exactly the same but in practice there will be a small, but negligible, difference. Too small to really matter, actually.

The basic idea is how array `b` is stored in memory. Because it is a lot larger, depending on your platform/implementation it might be stored in chunks, aka non-contiguously. That is likely since an array of 10 million ints is 40 million bytes = 40 MB!

EDIT: I get 572 and 593, respectively.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Java, but with the underlying OS. Most OSes do not consider memory as a single thing, but as a series of **pages** (chunks)...on my machine, pages are 32KB each. With an array as large as 40MB, it is split across multiple pages.

Comment: Yes, there's paging, and using many pages can lead to misses in the [TLB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer), but this is a probably minor issue compared to the normal cache miss costs. What I've found confusing is your claim about the non-continuous layout in the *physical* memory; this itself doesn't matter.

Comment: Of course not :P Although I never specified physical vs. virtual, all I was trying to do is convey the idea that `b` isn't one giant piece that can be iterated through as easily as `a`, and this is what's probably causing the difference, however small.

Comment: OK. Actually, 1000 ints fit in the L1 cache while 10000000 ints don't even fit into L3. So there should be some orders of magnitude difference. :D OK, prefetching, I see...

Answer (score 1):

The **first loop runs faster** on my system (median: 333 ms vs. 596 ms)
*(Edit: I made a wrong assumption on number of array accesses in my first response, see comments)*

Subsequent **incremental** (index++) accesses to the same array seem to be **faster** than random accesses or decremental (index--) accesses. I assume the **Java Hotspot compiler** can **optimize the array bound checks** if it recognizes that the array will be incrementally traversed.

**When reversing the loops, it actually runs slower:**

```
//incremental array index
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) {
        a[i]++;
    }
}

//decremental array index
for (int i = 1000 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 10000000 - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        a[i]++;
    }
}
```

**Incremental: 349ms, decremental: 485ms.**
Without bounds checks, decremental loops usually are faster, especially on old processors (comparing to zero).

If my assumption is right, this makes 1000 optimized bounds checks versus 10000000 checks, so the first method is faster.

By the way, when benchmarking:

- **Do multiple rounds** and **compare the averages/mediums** instead of the first sample
- In Java: give your benchmark a **warmup-phase** (execute it a few times before measuring). On the first run, classes have to be loaded, and code might be interpreted before the **HotSpot** VM feature kicks in and does a **native compilation**
- Measure time deltas with `System.nanoTime()`. This gives **more accurate timestamps**. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is not that precise (depends on the VM), and usually 'hops' in junks of a dozen or more milliseconds, rendering your result times more volatile than they actually are. Btw: 1 milliseconds = 1'000'000 nano second.

Comment: They have the same amount of array accesses.

Comment: aaah, you're right, my bad, will edit my respose, thanks Dukeling

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the they are both pretty much the same. One of them has a smaller array to handle, but that wouldn't make much difference except for the initial allocation of memory, which is outside your measuring anyway.

The time to execute each iteration should be the same (writing a value into an array). incrementing larger numbers shouldn't take the JVM longer than incrementing smaller numbers, nor should addressing a smaller or larger array index.

But why the question if you already know how to measure yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Check out big-oh notation

A nested for loop is O(n^2) - They will run the same in theory.

The numbers 1000 or 100000 are a constant k O(n^2 + k)

They won't be exactly identical in practise because of various other things at play but it will be close.

Comment: They clearly have the same theoretical running time. It looks like the question is about the actual running time.

Answer (score 0):

Time should be equal, the result will obviously be different since a will contain 1000 entries with value 10000 and b will contain 10000000 entries with value 1000. I don't really get your question. What's the result for end-start? 
It might be that the JVM will optimize the forloops, if it understands what the end results will be in the array than the smallest array will be much easier to calculate, since it requires only 1000 assignments, while the other one needs 10 000 times more.

Answer (score 0):

First will be fuster. Because of initialization of first `a` and `i` cell much more less times.

Comment: The initialization is not included in the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Modern architectures are complex, so answering this kind of question is never easy.

The run time could be same or the first could be faster.

Things to consider in this case is mostly memory access and optimization.

A good optimizer will realize that the values are never read, so the loops can be skipped entirely, which gives a run time of 0 in both cases. Such optimization can take place at [compile time](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2012/120905-jvm-performance-optimization-compilers.html) or at [run-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot).

If it isn't optimized away, then there is memory access to consider. `a[]` is much smaller than `b[]`, so it will more readily fit in faster cache memory resulting in fewer [cache misses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss).

Another thing to consider is [memory interleaving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaved_memory).